# Failed to spawn: unable to find process with name 'o-paus'

Tags: android, frida

what should i do,
when i do `frida -U -f Telegram -l freda.js — -no-whale` and it exits like
Failed to spawn: unable to find process with name 'o-paus'

Comment: What smartphone do you use Android or iOS?

Comment: Im use nox , ( emulator android )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only start an app using it's package name but in your example you are using the app name "Telegram". The app name can only be used for attaching to running processes.

Considering this the correct command is:

```
frida -U -f org.telegram.messenger -l freda.js --no-pause
```